# Target element of array for collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

UPDATE: I wanted to let you know that I'd solved this problem, if not necessarily answered my own question. Rather than trying to target the element of the push array, I did this:

In

```
var ground=[], water=[], enemies=[], environment=[];
```

I added

```
tokens=[];
```

to the end.

Then I wrote a new function, updateTokens:

```
function updateTokens() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        tokens[i].update();
        tokens[i].draw();

        if (player.minDist(tokens[i]) <= player.width - platformWidth / 2) {
            gameOver();
        }
    }

    if (tokens[0] && tokens[0].x < - platformWidth) {
        tokens.splice(0, 1);
    }
}
```

(The 'gameOver();' function is just for testing purposes).
Then I added 'spawnTokensSprites();' to the spawnSprites(); function.
Next, I wrote a new function to spawnTokensSprites:

```
function spawnTokensSprites() {
    if (score > 0 && rand(0, 20) === 0 && platformHeight < 3 {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            tokens.push(new Sprite(
                canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed,
                platformBase - platformHeight * platformSpacer - platformWidth,
                'tokens'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added 'updateTokens();' to the animate function, and finally, I added 'tokens=[]' to the 'startGame()' function.
So there it is. Not the answer to the  original question, but a working solution to the problem I had. I hope this can help someone else, which is why I updated my post.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm well out of my depth here. I've been following [this](http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-game-tutorial-module-pattern/) tutorial to make an HTML5 canvas game. It's great, and I've learned loads, but I'm totally stuck. 
I have a vector for sprites

```
function Sprite(x, y, type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = platformWidth;
    this.height = platformWidth;
    this.type = type;
    Vector.call(this, x, y, 0, 0);

    this.update = function () {
        this.dx = -player.speed;
        this.advance();
    };

    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
        ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs[this.type], this.x, this.y);
        ctx.restore();
    };
}
Sprite.prototype = Object.create(Vector.prototype);
```

from which all sprites inherit. To generate 'token' sprites, I use this function:

```
function spawnEnvironmentSprites() {
    if (score > 0 && rand(0, 20) === 0 && platformHeight < 3) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            environment.push(new Sprite(
                canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed,
                platformBase - platformHeight * 2 * platformSpacer - platformWidth,
                'tokens'
            ));
        }
        else if (platformLength > 2) {
            environment.push(new Sprite(
                canvas.width + platformWidth % player.speed,
                platformBase - platformHeight * 1.5 * platformSpacer - platformWidth,
                'tokens'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Which draws the sprites to the screen. What I cannot do is single these type of sprites out from the array for collision detection. I've tried to use an 'if' statement from the 'updateEnemies' function:

```
 if (player.minDist(enemies[i]) <= player.width - platformWidth/2) {
      gameOver();
   }
  }
```

within the 'updateEnvironment' function, where I substitute 'enemies' for 'environment', but because I don't know how to specify 'tokens' from 'environment', using this line results in no environment sprites being drawn to the canvas, including platforms. Earlier today, I tried including 'tokens' in 'enemySprites', which worked in so much as when the player collided, the gameOver() function ran, but I couldn't then figure out how to give 'tokens' different behaviour (ie. Score increase rather than gameOver). I should mention that the sprites are called this way because of the assetLoader function I've used.
So long story short, how can I collide with 'tokens' and have everything else behave as it should?
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the array for environment is declared in a variable that looks like this:

```
var ground = [], water = [], enemies = [], environment = [];
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: Ok, I still haven't sorted this out but I've made a change that I think will make things a bit easier for you to help me with(!)
I've removed 'tokens' from the 'spawnEnvironmentSprites()' function and added a condition to 'spawnEnemySprites' that pushes 'tokens'. This means they now have the same behaviour as my other 'enemies' i.e.. gameOver() is run upon collision detection. My question now is, how do I target 'tokens' in this line of code so that I can give that collision different behaviour? I'd like the 'token' sprite to disappear and the score to increase, but I don't know how to target just the 'tokens' part of the array. The line that deals with the collisions is:

```
 if (player.minDist(enemies[i]) <= player.width - platformWidth/2) {
  gameOver();
  }
 }
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance.